# RSA exponent d is negative

Tags: c++, boost, rsa

Im trying to encrypt and decrypt various messages with RSA and while it is working flawlessly while `d` is positive, it obviously breaks when `d` is negative as `d` is supposed to be a natural number.

I am using the `EXTENDED_EUCLID` algorithm to find it and the code is as follows.

```
void EXTENDED_EUCLID(cpp_int a, cpp_int b, cpp_int&d, cpp_int&x, cpp_int&y) {
     cpp_int n_d = d,
             n_x = x,
             n_y = y;

      if(b == 0) {
          d = a;
          x = 1;
          y = 0;
      } else {      
          cpp_int n_a = a % b;
          if (n_a < 0) n_a += b;
          EXTENDED_EUCLID(b, n_a, n_d, n_x, n_y);
          d = n_d;
          x = n_y;
          y = n_x - a / b * n_y;
      }
}
```

The 2 lines of code before the recursive call `EXTENDED_EUCLID(b, n_a, n_d, n_x, n_y);` are from a solution I found on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10805/how-does-one-deal-with-a-negative-d-in-rsa. Obviously I am doing something wrong here, maybe they need to be positioned somewhere else?

The initial call of the `EXTENDED_EUCLID` is made with the following parameters `EXTENDED_EUCLID(a, n, d, x, y);` from a function named `MODULAR_LINEAR_EQUATION_SOLVER`. `a` in this case is `e`(public key if I'm not mistaken) and `n` or `b` in this case are `φ(n)`.

Thank you for donating your time to this, hopefully not too silly question.

Comment: please provide a [mre], where does your input come from? If `d` is supposed to not be negative why are you testing with it set to a negative number?

Comment: I am not testing it with a negative number, p,q, and e are pseudo randoms. Whether d is negative is up to chance.

Comment: So d should be a unsigned instead of a signed number?

Comment: Yes it should be an unsigned number, but that isn't always the case here. One solution is described in the link I included in the question, but it isn't working for me.

Comment: The extended euclidean algorithm is used to compute an inverse, but it may correctly produce negative numbers. If when computing the inverse mod phi you get a negative number then simply add phi to it.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk See, thats the thing thats bothering me... I know I'm suppose to do that, but the code where I check and do that is either in the wrong spot or it's something else that I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Understood. What I would do is implement a method called ModInverse that calls ExtendedEuclid. If the value returned from ExtendedEuclid is negative, then add the modulus to it. You shouldn't modify ExtendedEuclid.

Comment: I do have a method called MODULAR_LINEAR_EQUATION_SOLVER, where the initial call to EXTENDED_EUCLID is made. I did what you said and it worked, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to move the 2 lines of code that are above the `EXTENDED_EUCLID(b, n_a, n_d, n_x, n_y);` recursive call to the function `MODULAR_LINEAR_EQUATION_SOLVER`, below the initial `EXTENDED_EUCLID` call. Many thanks to President James K. Polk.